# Parsing this data, where do I start?

Tags: python

This is a snippet of the file that I want to parse, the sections are repeated over and over ~400 times in the same txt file. It just goes

-Per port stats table

-Global stats enabled

-Latency stats enabled

-Per port stats table

... it just keeps going again and again until it gets to another section that starts with "*** TRex is shutting down - cause: 'test has ended'" I con't care about anything after that. Only the 3 sections listed above.

```
-Per port stats table
      ports |               0 |               1
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   opackets |          114117 |          153632
     obytes |        32327952 |       183601935
   ipackets |               0 |               0
     ibytes |               0 |               0
    ierrors |               0 |               0
    oerrors |               0 |               0
      Tx Bw |       0.00  bps |       0.00  bps

-Global stats enabled
 Cpu Utilization : 0.0  %  0.0 Gb/core
 Platform_factor : 1.0
 Total-Tx        :       0.00  bps
 Total-Rx        :       0.00  bps
 Total-PPS       :       0.00  pps
 Total-CPS       :       0.00  cps

 Expected-PPS    :       2.15 Mpps
 Expected-CPS    :      41.23 Kcps
 Expected-BPS    :      10.04 Gbps

 Active-flows    :     4865  Clients :      511   Socket-util : 0.0155 %
 Open-flows      :    16307  Servers :     5621   Socket :     4981 Socket/Clients :  9.7
 drop-rate       :       0.00  bps
 current time    : 1.6 sec
 test duration   : 98.4 sec

-Latency stats enabled
 Cpu Utilization : 0.0 %
 if|   tx_ok , rx_ok  , rx check ,error,       latency (usec) ,    Jitter          max window
   |         ,        ,          ,     ,   average   ,   max  ,    (usec)
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0 |      507,       0,         0,    0,          0  ,       0,       0      |  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 1 |      507,       0,         0,    0,          0  ,       0,       0      |  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I am trying to create a csv file that stores each metric and its value for every "current time" under the -Global stats enabled section. Each metric would have different values for every timestamp and I am trying to track that value as the current time goes up. Could I get a few pointers and rabbit holes to follow? The ultimate goal is to import the data into graphana or something similar.

The -Latency stats enabled section is the least important.

Thank you
p.s. I have python 2.7.10 or 2.7.5 installed...

Comment: elcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0):

- A loop with a proper `try` `except` for cacthing errors at the end of parsing
- Determining the structure of your data, line and column separators, headers
- Take care of trailing spaces
- The `[split][1]` function may be a very good friend